# Where is .gitignore located in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following Michael Hartl's Rails 4.0 tutorial and he suggests changing the input of the .gitignore file. Where is it located on a mac?

Comment: create one if it is not existing i.e `touch .gitignore` from your rails app folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the root of the rails application.

```
cd /path/to/rails/app
ls -alF
```

You should see `.gitignore` along with the default application files.

Comment: Ok I see it but how do I open it @Ken?

Comment: On a mac `open .gitignore` will open the file in your default text editor.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an application `.gitignore` file located in your Rails app's application folder. I can see it here in Sublime Text, for example.

[image: I can see it here in Sublime Text, for example].

Comment: I would like to know how you got that sexy Sublime Text skin :P

Comment: @maltray That's the Solarized theme, installable from Package Control.